# Change Gradle's working directory when compiling a Groovy project

Tags: groovy, gradle

When compiling a groovy project, gradle creates files in `$projectRoot/build/`.  Is there a way to configure this to e.g. an absolute path?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can put the following line in your build script:

```
buildDir = 'your_directory'
```

Or in `gradle.properties` file (no quotes around `your_directory` in that case).

---

Build directory is a project property. You can view all project properties available to you by typing:

```
gradle properties
```

Comment: Windows absolute path like `buildDir = 'R:\\buildMaria'` worked in `build.gradle` but failed in `gradle.properties`  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116000/gradle-make-use-of-ramdisk

Comment: can it be done with some env variable? i need it to configure CI for the project

Comment: So,t he key for `gradle.properties` is `project.buildDir=new/directory/location`?

Answer (score 7):

You can set `project.buildDir` in your `build.gradle`, or `buildDir = PATH` in `gradle.properties`.

And from environment variable like this:

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Dorg.gradle.project.buildDir=/tmp/gradle-build
```

See Build Environment section of the documentation here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables

And Writing Build Scripts here (for buildDir property):
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

*(Current version of gradle when writing this: 4.5)*

Comment: gradle build -Dorg.gradle.project.buildDir=build-2/

Works too

Answer (score 3):

You can add project.buildDir = 'your/directory' to the file **build.gradle**
you can place it anywhere in separate line