# Gradle - make use of RAMdisk

Tags: gradle, ramdisk

I just run into idea of using [RAMdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) for compilation results [1](http://docs.robovm.com/user/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#ram%20disks)

How to use RAMdisk with Gradle?

I guess it is worth moving `.gradle` and `build` folders into  RAMdisk.

Comment: Have you noticed some benefit using RAMdisk with Gradle?

Comment: It is much quicker.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just for completeness, here's how I configured Gradle (and thereby also Android Studio) on Ubuntu 14.04 to always build to RAM disk:

My **`~/.bashrc`** contains this line in the end:

```
. ~/bin/mkramdisk  # Setup personal RAM disk on login.
```

My **`~/bin/mkramdisk`** is listed below.  I suppose you could omit this script and simply use e.g. `/dev/shm/${System.env.USER}/gradle-builds`in the following step, but I like to have a general RAM disk for other purposes as well, for instance I use it for my `$TMP`.  Anyway, here goes:

```
# Setup personal RAM disk.

# This script should be sourced, hence the missing +x flag.
# Source it from e.g. from ~/.bashrc or run it from crontab
# at @reboot event.  Doesn't work with encrypted homedir, though!

export RAMDISK=$HOME/tmp/ramdisk
if [ ! -d $RAMDISK ]; then
        [ -d /dev/shm/$USER-ramdisk ] || install -vd /dev/shm/$USER-ramdisk -o $USER -m 700
        [ -d ~/tmp ] || mkdir -v ~/tmp
        [ -L ~/tmp/ramdisk ] || ln -vs /dev/shm/$USER-ramdisk ~/tmp/ramdisk
fi

# Use personal RAM disk for $TMP.
export TMP=$RAMDISK
```

*NOTE to Macintosh users: It seems you can modify `mkramdisk` to instead contain [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359182/2412477) command to make it work on your system.*

To finally answer the question, my **`~/.gradle/init.gradle`** is this:

```
println "Loaded personal ~/.gradle/init.gradle"

gradle.projectsLoaded {
    rootProject.allprojects {
        buildDir = "${System.env.RAMDISK}/gradle-builds/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
        println "BUILDING TO RAMDISK: buildDir=$buildDir"
    }
}
```

Remove debug `println` statements as you see fit.

Answer (score 9):

in root `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "/path/to/build/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

See also

- [Gradle global build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340946/gradle-global-build-directory)
- [Change gradle build directory in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008485/change-gradle-build-directory-in-android-studio)
- [Change Gradle's working directory when compiling a Groovy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915351/change-gradles-working-directory-when-compiling-a-groovy-project)

and docs https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html