# Gradle How to Set Output Root Path

Tags: groovy, gradle, root

My sources are in a folder structure like:

mygitroot/myproj/module1/src/main/groovy/com/mypak/module1
mygitroot/myproj/module2/src/main/groovy/com/mypak/module2
mygitroot/myproj/module3/src/main/groovy/com/mypak/module3

Gradle builds the jars in a folder structure like:

mygitroot/myproj/build/libs/module1.jar
mygitroot/myproj/build/libs/module2.jar
mygitroot/myproj/build/libs/module3.jar

I want it to output to the default dynamic folder structure, just rooted to a different "nongitroot" folder:

mybuildroot/myproj/build/libs/module1.jar
mybuildroot/myproj/build/libs/module2.jar
mybuildroot/myproj/build/libs/module3.jar

my task says this:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    group 'Build'
    description 'An archive of the source code'
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

Is there an elegant way to change just the root?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Gradle's working directory when compiling a Groovy project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915351/change-gradles-working-directory-when-compiling-a-groovy-project)

Comment: Set `buildDir` property

Comment: Does not work as requested:

Comment: Does not work as requested, I'm guessing because "modules1-3" are subprojects of a parent project.  I added  buildDir="../my-build" under allprojects{  and it did create the folder and create "my-build/libs/parent.jar" and "my-build/temp".  But it also created "my-build" in the root of my project, with "/classes", "/libs", and "/tmp" subdirs.  Inside "/libs" were all 3 jars.... "module1.jar", "module2.jar", "module3.jar"  .  Very surprising.  So, it seems I would need to specify each subprojects buildDir statically, in the build.gradle for each module (example: "myproj/src/module1" ). Correct?

Comment: Just set buildDir on the parent project, not the sub projects.

Comment: But as I said, it doesn't do what I asked.

Comment: Why don't you just build them as normal, then have a task that moves them. Would that not be easier than trying to hack the build path for jar files?

Comment: Because nobody had suggested that until now :) Thanks Tim!   Also, I didn't think it would be a hack, i thought it would just be a configurable thing, like most "path" variables.  I'll move as you suggested, but selectively moving only subfolders that contain JAR to a new place, and maintaining the folder structure will be a non-trivial script. Also, this is my first project with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Using answer from tim_yates - It turns out this is not a configurable option in Gradle, and thus is not natively possible.  Going to create a move task instead.